# How to let stata recognize double slash?

Tags: stata

I want to perform character replacement in Stata, but the character is a website address with a `//` symbol, which is recognized as a comment by Stata. How can I let Stata replace the `//` character in the data?

My code:

```
replace _var = subinstr(_var, "'><div class=td1 style='width:220px'><a href=http://www.crei.cn/tudi/tdbr.aspx?id=202402050956141715 target=_blank class=tdbrw>', "123", .)
```

Thanks！

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Stata's interpreter interprets that line as a comment. I think the issue is that you are missing a `"` to close the string with `html` code you want to replace.

In my do-file editor parts of that code gets the green syntax highlighting that is associated with comments. I think that is likely to be a bug in the syntax highlighting. But the syntax highlighting is different from how the code is interpreted by Stata when you are running the code.

Note that I am using compounded quotes. Meaning `` `""' `` instead of `""`. This makes handling of strings that may include `"` much more robust. And an `html` page might very well include double quotes.

This example below worked for me:

```
local string "LOREM IPSUM'><div class=td1 style='width:220px'><a href=http://www.crei.cn/tudi/tdbr.aspx?id=202402050956141715 target=_blank class=tdbrw>'LOREM IPSUM"

local new_string =  subinstr(`"`string'"', `"'><div class=td1 style='width:220px'><a href=http://www.crei.cn/tudi/tdbr.aspx?id=202402050956141715 target=_blank class=tdbrw>'"', "123", .) 

di `"`new_string'"'
```